# Mojave 32 Bit Apps: Finder dialogue boxes are slow

Tags: mojave

When using a 32 Bit app on Mojave, parts of the App that use the Finder are very slow (e.g. Open/Save dialogue boxes). Sometimes I can take over a minute to select an option in these dialogue boxes.

Is there any way to fix this?

I know that 32-bit apps aren't supported after Mojave, but Mojave does support them.

I am using OS 10.14.5 on a MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015 (aka MacBookPro11,5).

Affected Apps: Indesign CS6, Acrobat Pro, Aquia Dev Desktop (Acquia Dev Desktop Version: 2 Built: Sep 19 201)
All my other apps are 64 bit and work fine.

Comment: Can you name the apps where you are experiencing this?

Comment: Do you have any external hard drives that might have gone to sleep and need to spin up? That's the usual issue for Carbon file dialogs.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema InDesign CS6, Acquia Dev Desktop

Comment: @benwiggy The only drive I have connected is Time Machine. Would that cause an issue?

Comment: If the hard drive has gone to sleep, then it will take 30 seconds or so to spin up. You should be able to hear if that is happening. I have InDesign CS6 and I don't see this problem, but don't have HDDs.

Comment: @benwiggy The time capsule drive is connected wirelessly. Is there any way I can temporarily disable it to see if it is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What View are you using? Some apps aren't keen on Icon view (& they hated CoverFlow ;)

Comment: It is unlikely that Finder is slow because of 32-bit apps. On my Macs there is no noticeable difference in open/save sheets between 32 and 64-bit apps. There is likely something else happening on your system.

Comment: Fwiw, I have experienced something like this in Mojave with 32bit apps, such as Fetch. However, it's not anywhere near as severe for me as what the asker is describing.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am using list view

Comment: @Steve Chambers I did a clean reinstall and it still happens. It happened on High Sierra too.

Comment: Make and model of your Mac, plus the apps it happens in and the apps it does not. Add that to your original question *not as a comment!*

Comment: @SteveChambers Updated.

Comment: I was thinking that *maybe* you had a dual graphics "card" Mac and one of the cards was failing. But that model only uses the Intel Iris Pro graphics engine on the CPU/CPU chipset... grrr... You may want to check out the Adobe forums and post there about your issues with mac/OS/App versions and see if someone has an idea. Sorry, I've run out of ideas...